# Why does Activity Pub make servers wrap "Note" objects into "Create" activities?

Tags: json-ld, linked-data, activity-streams, activitypub

What I've gathered is that new posts are published by POSTing a JSON-LD Activity Streams object of type `Note` to an actor's outbox.

```
{"@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
 "type": "Note",
 "to": ["https://chatty.example/ben/"],
 "attributedTo": "https://social.example/alyssa/",
 "content": "Say, did you finish reading that book I lent you?"}
```

The server will then have wrap it into an activity of type `Create`.

```
{"@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
 "type": "Create",
 "id": "https://social.example/alyssa/posts/a29a6843-9feb-4c74-a7f7-081b9c9201d3",
 "to": ["https://chatty.example/ben/"],
 "actor": "https://social.example/alyssa/",
 "object": {"type": "Note",
            "id": "https://social.example/alyssa/posts/49e2d03d-b53a-4c4c-a95c-94a6abf45a19",
            "attributedTo": "https://social.example/alyssa/",
            "to": ["https://chatty.example/ben/"],
            "content": "Say, did you finish reading that book I lent you?"}}
```

I fail to see the usefulness of this, as the wrapping activity doesn't seem to add any useful data to the wrapped note. Worse even, it seems like it might introduce a fair bit of redundancy to the responses (in this basic example from the [official page](https://www.w3.org/TR/activitypub/), `actor` and `attributedTo`, as well as the 2 `to` fields, have exactly the same purpose). Is this perhaps done just for consistency, as there are a few other other activity types that are applied to notes, and for newly created posts having just a plain object (or a collection of plain objects) as a response would not fit this way of doing things?

Also, why are other activity types (e.g., `Like`) able to simply reference notes by id, while `Create` activities enclose that data directly? Is that required or is there a specific reason for it?

```
{"@context": "https://www.w3.org/ns/activitystreams",
 "type": "Like",
 "id": "https://social.example/alyssa/posts/5312e10e-5110-42e5-a09b-934882b3ecec",
 "to": ["https://chatty.example/ben/"],
 "actor": "https://social.example/alyssa/",
 "object": "https://chatty.example/ben/p/51086"}
```

Answer (score -1):

ActivityStreams is a protocole to synchronise datas between different databases and softwares.

Some actions contain the detail (like for Notes) because we can create/update them and an activity stream reader must know the changes to display the good datas to its users.

Some operations like Like have a named cancel operation like Unlike. So we don't need the Create/Update container. and because they operate on existing datas, we also only need the unique ID to the concerned resource.